# How to add realistic shadows to sprite kit (Swift 3)

Tags: sprite-kit, swift3

Apparently the SpriteKit's shadow  falloff does not work. Is there anyway to fix this? Thank you
[image]

Comment: is this a light used to create a shadow?

Comment: Yes, it is a SKLightNode @Confused